# Angular ngInclude $on($includeContentLoaded) firing before all content loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui

I am using Angular ngInclude to include a partial HTML that contains a set of embedded JqueryUI Accordions.

```
        <div ng-controller="startLessonController as slCtrl">
        <div class="accordionLevel">
            <div ng-repeat="level in course.level" >
              <h2> {{level.number}} - {{level.name}}: {{level.title}}</h2>
                <div >
                    <span ng-bind-html="level.description"></span>
                    <div class="accordionLesson" ng-include=" 'LessonMenuTemplate.html'  ">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I included the code to initialize the accordions within the $scope.$on($includeContentLoaded) function.

```
$scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function () {
    $( ".accordianLevel" ).accordion({
        header: "h2",
        collapsible: true,
        active:false,
        heightStyle:"content"
    });
```

The above works fine for the first accordion level (which is outside of the ng-include).  However the two child accordion initializations that are within the included HTML area not in the DOM by the time $includeContentLoaded fires.

I've worked around the problem by putting in a setTimeout() with a delay before initializing the inner accordions.

```
    $scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function () {
    $( ".accordionLevel" ).accordion({
        header: "h2",
        collapsible: true,
        active:false,
        heightStyle:"content"
    });
    setTimeout(function () {
        $( ".accordionLesson" ).accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            header: "h3",
            active:false,
            heightStyle:"content"
        });
        $( ".accordionPath" ).accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            header: "h4",
            active:false,
            heightStyle:"content"
        });
    }, 100);
});
```

The concern I have is network latency may make the above fail since my delay is a guess as to when the DOM is completely updated.  I could test to see if $(.accordionPath) is empty and retry after another delay, but since there are multiple occurrences of the element I won't know if it partially loaded.

Is there a better place to put my accordion initialization logic?

Comment: You aren't supposed to put dom modifying code directly in your controller, that's what a directive is for.  If you make your own directive then in that directive you can tell when that particular element has been loaded and in turn do your init call

Comment: How about counting the number of times `$includeContentLoaded` has been emitted?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably NOT the best answer within "Angular" design practices, but, faced with the identical problem, I have "solved" it in the following manner:

Create a tiny directive and restrict it to 'A' (attributes).  Then, add the attribute-directive to your accordion `<div>` - you can embed it into a partial html, or any other dynamic html code that would run through $compile.  Here is what I mean:

```
app.directive('myAccordionInit', function()
{
    var vDefinition =
    {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs)
        {
            setTimeout(function ()
            {
                element.accordion(
                {
                    collapsible: true,
                    header: h3,
                    active: false,
                    heightStyle: "content"
                });
            }, 100);
        }
    };
    return vDefinition;
});
```

The timeout is still a necessary precaution.

What seems to happen is that by the time your "Attribute" directives are processed, the dynamic DOM pretty much has been built and your "Attribute" is next to fire.  You are now attaching your code to the 'element' rather than a class, and Angular ***will*** pass you a valid element.  And so, even if there is much network latency, your execution is delayed along with it.

Incidentally, an added benefit of this approach is that you can put your accordion initialisation into other attributes of your `<div>`, i.e. `<div my-accordion-init header="h4">`, and then modify your directive to use them:

...

```
            element.accordion(
            {
                collapsible: true,
                header: attrs.header, // add others as necessary
                active: false,
                heightStyle: "content"
            });
```

...

Hopefully this helps,

Roman